# Why is this SQL query returning rows from outside of the specificed date range

Tags: sql, oracle, operator-precedence

I have the below query for a table that has records that include dates from Jan 1st - March 31st of a previous year. When I run this query as below there are some records returned that are beyond 2023-02-05, for example some records that are returned have an event_time of 2023-02-27. I'm not sure why I'm getting records beyond the specified date, I am expecting to only see records returned with an event_time between the two specified dates.

Can someone provide input on what is wrong with my query that is causing it to return rows beyond the specified dates?

Note I have also tried using BETWEEN like
`WHERE event_time BETWEEN to_date('2023-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND to_date('2023-02-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` but I get the same results.

```
SELECT id, event_time
FROM table
WHERE event_time >= to_date('2023-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND event_time <= to_date('2023-02-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND id = '541'OR id = '883' OR id = '959' OR id = '461'
ORDER BY event_time desc;
```

Using Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.22.0.0.0

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: The problem is with your combination of `AND` and `OR`. You likely need to add a parenthesis around these expressions: `AND id = '541'OR id = '883' OR id = '959' OR id = '461'`.

Comment: Even better: `AND id IN ('541', '883', '959', '461')`

Comment: Your question is fine, but yes, it's a problem with parentheses. `or` has lower precedence than.

Comment: That's a very good example why using `IN` should be prefered for such conditions

Comment: When you have a combination of `AND`s and `OR`s, *always* use `( )` to specify precedence. Then you don't need to worry about what goes before what - advice applicable to any language

Comment: Add parentheses around the `OR` conditions: `WHERE event_time >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND event_time < DATE '2023-02-06'
AND (id = '541'OR id = '883' OR id = '959' OR id = '461')` or use an `IN` expression rather than multiple `OR`s. Also, in Oracle, a `DATE` **ALWAYS** has a time component (even if the client application you are using does not show it) so `event_time <= DATE '2023-02-05'` will find dates less than or equal to `2023-02-05 00:00:00`. If you want the full 24 hour period for the last day then use `event_time < DATE '2023-02-06'`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, these answers cleared it up!